# Telegram - Node. Js handle multiple updates

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm creating a game on telegram and currently I have an issue about working with multiple updates at the same time. I'm using node.js

For example i have this code

```
var TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api'),    
  bot = new TelegramBot("MY_TOKEN", {polling: true});

bot.onText(/^\/createroom/, function (res, match) {

//Here i have some logic, to check whether if the room already created or not
service.checkIfRoomExist(res) // this service here, will always return false, because of the simultaneously chat
.then (function(isExist) {
 if (isExist === false) {
  service.createRoom(res)
  .then (function() {

  });
 }
});



//it works fine, if player type "/createroom" not simultaneously

//but if more than 1 player type "/createroom" simultaneously, my logic here doesn't work, it will create multiple room

}
```

Any thoughts to tackle this issue?

Thanks a lot, any help will be appreciated

Comment: So, you have written some code that does not work correctly? Why don't you show it?

Comment: @Tomalak, see my edited code above, thanks

Comment: You need to remove the "exists" check. Write a function that creates a room (or fails) and call that. The function ought to return a room object on success or throw an error. This way, the first incoming request succeeds, the second one fails.

Comment: @Tomalak, sorry man, i still don't get it. What do you mean is, just use the function createRoom right? It will always return success right? i still don't know, how some simultaneously chat will fail createRoom function. sorry, just still dont get it

Comment: Why would the "createRoom" function always return success? That doesn't even make sense. Either it could create a room or it could not.

Comment: @Tomalak, ahh okay, sorry, just got it. but dude, the reason why i check "exist" first, because there's some condition to be fulfilled, so i think to remove the "check" function, is not the right way? from my point of view... (because there's some condition to be fulfilled before they could create a room)

Comment: @Tomalak, do you mind to continue this discussion to chat? i'm afraid we're still not standing on the same shoes

Comment: You have a race condition here. When the "exists" check returns false now, this might not be the case a few processor ticks later. You are witnessing the effect live with your code. For the same reason node.js has deprecated "file exists" checks. If you want to create a file? Call "create" and catch the potential error. Open a file? Call "open" and catch the error. The same principle applies here. You don't need an exists check.

Comment: For example, if "creating a room" in your context  means creating a record in a database... Just create the record unconditionally. This fails or succeeds - the database does the duplicate check for you, the operation is atomic. All you need to do is to transfer the error or success to the requester. The first requester will win in this setup, the second one will be rejected, just as you intend.

Answer (score 2):

You need to link the unique chat/user ids to your database to prevent such conflicts. See the code below and comments on how to do it.

```js
var TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api'),
    bot = new TelegramBot("MY_TOKEN", {
        polling: true
    });

bot.onText(/^\/createroom/, function (res, match) {
    //use res.chat.id for groups and res.user.id for individuals
    service.checkIfRoomExist(res.chat.id).then(function (isExist) {
        if (isExist === false) {
            service.createRoom(res.chat.id).then(function () {
                bot.sendMessage(res.chat.id, 'Initializing game!')
                    // send game content here
            });
        }
        bot.sendMessage(res.chat.id, 'A game has already started in this group!')
    })
});

function checkIfRoomExist(id) {
    // Your logic here that checks in database if game has been created
}
```